# How to communicate with spring websocket

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, sockjs

I am trying to build an application where the server will keep pushing message to the client in some interval.
I have a simple html file like this.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="sockjs/sockjs.js"></script>
<script src="stomp/stomp.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click='connect()'>hi</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.connect = function() {
        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8099/myws');
        $scope.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        $scope.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected:bhabani ' + frame);
            $scope.stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8099/topic/jobconfig', function (wsdata) {
                console.log("helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
                console.log(wsdata);
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I opened the html file in the file system.
file:///export/data1/test-ws.html in the browser.

Now i have a spring web socket like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingController gc;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/myws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
        new Thread(gc).start();
    }

}
```

Have a greeting controller like this, which should push a message to the topic in some internal

```
@Component
public class GreetingController implements Runnable{

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true){
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            template.convertAndSend("/topic/jobconfig", new Greeting("hi"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Where i press the connect button i can see connection is established.
But after that i do not see any message coming in the browser which should be pushed from the server.

I am expecting the 'helloooooooooooo' message should be printed in my browser console in each interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change URL in stomp client subscribe code from this `http://localhost:8099/topic/jobconfig` to this `/topic/jobconfig`.

```
$scope.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/jobconfig', function(wsdata) {
                    console.log("hello");
                    console.log(wsdata);
                });
```